# MySQL Creating an Advanced Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

### Summary

So I have 3 tables, which I have screenshots below.   Every user will get 10 slides by default when they sign up, so that information is in the "slides" table.  The template_id is just another table I have which is identical to the `custom_slides` table except there are 10 pre-made slides which are default slides, so if I ever want to update the page name of a default slide, I just do it once in that template table.

If the slide is a custom slide, then template_id will be NULL just like you see for Slide 11, and slide 11 gets put in the custom_slides table.

---

### What I need

So I need help writing a query to get some information.  I want to grab the slide_id, the sort_order, and the page_name for a certain user.

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT slide_id, sort_order FROM `user_slides` WHERE user_id = 1
```

Now I need to grab the page_name but I need to run a separate query.

- Check slide_id on the slides table and see if template_id is NULL or has a value.
- if it has a value then it is a default slide, so if the template_id is 3 then I need to run a query to get the page_name from the templates table where template_id = 3
- if template_id is NULL then I need to run a query to look for the page_name in custom_slides table where slide_id = whatever slide id.

I'm not too experienced yet with running multiple queries and UNION and all of that, so if someone could help me get started in creating this query I would really appreciate it.

---

### Table Previews

**user_slides**

[image]

**slides**

[image]

**custom_slides**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this query should fetch the data you want:

```
SELECT slide_id, sort_order, COALESCE(`templates`.page_name, `custom_slides`.page_name)  
FROM `user_slides` 
JOIN `slides` ON `slides`.slide_id = `user_slides` .slide_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `templates` ON `templates`.template_id = `slides`.template_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `custom_slides` ON `slides`.template_id IS NULL AND `custom_slides`.slide_id = `slides`.slide_id
WHERE `user_slides`.user_id = 1
```

**Clarification:**
This is basically the select query you posted with a few joins.
First the `slides` table is joined matching the slide_id.
Then the `templates` table is joined, the outer join makes sure the rows where template_id is NULL are still included. And last the `custom_slides` table is joined but only if template_id is NULL. then using `COALESCE` we select the page name from either `custom_slides` or `templates`.

Comment: the use of COALESCE is a nice touch!

Answer (score 1):

you can try with two left joins on the templates table (you didn't give a name so I just called it "templates" in my example) and on the custom_slides table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_slides us
INNER JOIN slides s 
  ON us.slide_id = s.slide_id
LEFT JOIN templates t
  ON s.template_id=t.template_id
LEFT JOIN custom_slides cs
  ON s.slide_id = cs.slide_id
WHERE user_id = 1
```

this should return all the rows in `user_slides` and `slides` even if there are no corresponding rows in `templates` (i.e. in your case when the `template_id` in `slides` is NULL) or in custom_slides (i.e. if the `slide_id` is not a custom slide and so does not exist in the `custom_slides` table).

However you should still have some logic in the application layer (assuming there is an application running the query and using the results) to check if template_id is NULL or not and use the custom_slides if it is.